# Payment methods not working in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment

On our website wijnmaat.nl we are trying to integrate the paypal, bank transfer and Ideal payment methods. We were able to get the bank transfer working but the Ideal and Paypal pay methods are giving us a 500 internal server error:

***Problem: Paypal according Google Chrome console***

```
PUT http://www.wijnmaat.nl/rest/netherlands/V1/carts/mine/selected-payment-method 500 (Internal server error)

 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.process (error-processor.js:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (set-payment-method.js:50)
at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)process @ error processor.js:19 (anonymous) @ set-payment-method.js:50 j @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 fireWith @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 x @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4(anonymous) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
```

Answer (score 0):

The 500 internal server error could be one of many, many issues.  But it's usually a server configuration issue.

I would first make sure that file permissions are set properly using the chmod command.

Second, I'd ensure the correct ownership of the files.  For example, if you're logged in via SSH as user xyz123 (and uploaded or edited files using this user), but the files need to run as www-data, then you'll want to use the chown command to change the ownership.

Third, make sure you do a static content deploy, and clear all of the caches.

I would try testing this out in both developer and production mode, to see if there is a difference in the errors.